# Which is best method for calling a required servlet

Tags: java, servlets, httpclient

I have a desktop application from where a client can add a new user, can chat with other user etc... I have 2 options now:

1. To make a handler servlet which will get post request on
   according to request the handler servlet will call required
   servlet(e.g `loginServlet`, `chatServlet` , `addUserServlet` etc)
2. Directly call the required servlet from client e.g make direct
   request to chatServlet for `chat`, `login` and `addUser`

Remember my client side is a desktop application. Which method is good for implementing and future enhancements. 
Thank you

Comment: I think you should just call URLs using httpclient and map different servlets to different URLs in web-inf.xml file as done by normal web applications.

Comment: @Reddy thankyou for making my question more readable..thanks for editing.

Comment: Do you have a Web Application where you will deploy this servlet? Otherwise, the question has no much sense.

Comment: @Reddy What if in future i want to update my application should i change client side too in this case.. i am new developer that's why i am a bit confuse.?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoze .. defiantly brother i have web Application and i have to deploy it..

Comment: you will communicate with web applications to specific URLs using HTTP. It doesn't make any difference that yours is a desktop application as you will be making HTTP calls only to the web application. 

What do you mean by "update my application"?

Comment: @Reddy Means...future enhancements, new version of applications etc..

Comment: I don't understand your concerns actually. But the answer is "it depends on how you implement and not on how you would call servlets". If you have to use it Servlets then you will have to do it servlets way. Otherwise you may go through RMI way.

Comment: brother one way is for chat make httpClient post request at e.g("http://localhost:8080/Test/chatServlet) from client side..other way it to always call (http://localhost:8080/Test/HandlerServlet) form client and depending on the request handler servlet will decide weather to call chatServlet or other..hope you get the idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,I think you should go with the 1 st Approach by using **Front Controller pattern**.

It should consist of only a **SINGLE SERVLET** which provides a centralized entry point for all requests.This servlet will **delegate** all request to the required servlet.

You need to do only following thing to apply the front controller pattern in your application:

```
       <servlet>
       <servlet-name>////servlet name: FrontController</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>////Fully qualified servlet name e.g: org.chat.controller.FrontController</servlet-class>
       </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FrontController<servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thank you brother for showing approach but...can you please give me a couple of advantage of this approach upon the other one..? so that i can justify in my documentation that why i choose this approach.

Comment: ya sure,The basic idea behind using FrontController design pattern is to reduce the duplicate code,exception handling,testability.

Comment: See,in your scenario it will help you to reduce the duplicate code that your going to right like the Chat Session starts and chat session completed in every controller.
You might want to write custom exceptions or your servlet handles some exceptions.The exception handling code will be written only in Frontcontroller so that no need to write it in every controller.

The Common logic will be written only in front controller like session management,authentication.So it will reduce the lines of code and helps you in testing.
Your loginServlet,chatServlet... will only have the required logic.

Comment: But shouldn't you use Servlet filters for these things?

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't clearly understand your problem from the question. But I would suggest you would start with approach 2 and start implement.
If you face any specific problems then post here.